# Как для GridView связанной таблицы сделать выборку не всех полей '*'?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть `GridView` с пользователями.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [                        
        [
            'attribute' => 'userType',
            'value' => 'userType.Name',
            'filter' => false,
        ],
        'username',            
    ],
]); ?>
```

У пользователя есть тип (`userType`). Если в параметр `query` класса `ActiveDataProvider` присваивать `User::find()`, то выборка будет ленивой и результат запросов на странице будет:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user`
SELECT * FROM `user` LIMIT 20
SELECT * FROM `usertypes` WHERE `UserTypeId`=1
SELECT * FROM `usertypes` WHERE `UserTypeId`=1
SELECT * FROM `usertypes` WHERE `UserTypeId`=2
```

Если выборку делать жадной `$query = User::find()->joinWith('userType');` , то результат будет:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` LEFT JOIN `usertypes` ON `user`.`UserTypeId` = `usertypes`.`UserTypeId`
SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` LEFT JOIN `usertypes` ON `user`.`UserTypeId` = `usertypes`.`UserTypeId` LIMIT 20
SELECT * FROM `usertypes` WHERE `UserTypeId` IN (1, 2)
```

---

Вопрос: могу ли я как-то повлиять на ленивую/жадную загрузку так, чтобы выборка была не через звездочку **'*'**, а с указанными мною полями? Ибо если таблица большая, то делать выборку всех полей не совсем корректно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`joinWith` можно оформить как массив, где ключом выступает имя связи, а значением может быть анонимная функция, которая принимает на вход `\yii\db\ActiveQuery`, с которым можно уже производить стандартные действия с таблицей. Итог:

```
User::find()->joinWith(['userType' => function(\yii\db\ActiveQuery $q) {
    return $q->select([/* fields */]);
}]);
```